CMake generator expression with spaces after commas behaving unexpectedly
I am building a source file using "add_custom_command". The compiler is MS Visual Studio. CMake version is 3.29. I am trying to get the intermediate object file directory using the generator expressions, and to set it as the working directory as shown below.
ADD_LIBRARY(MyTarget SHARED ${MY_SRC})
add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget PRE_LINK COMMAND ${BINARY_EXE} ARGS -o myargs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file  
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY "$<PATH:GET_PARENT_PATH, $<LIST:GET, $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyTarget>,0>>" COMMENT "Build started" VERBATIM)

In this code, the expression $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyTarget> returns "only" a list containing all the object files already generated. I am expecting this expression ( $<LIST:GET, $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyTarget>,0>) to return the first item in the list. But it is returning two paths separated by space. One is the root build directory (not sure how it came) and the second one is the expected first item from the list. So, $<PATH:GET_PARENT_PATH returns two paths. May I know why I am getting two paths as output to $<LIST:GET> generator expression.

I think the spaces are treated as part of the subexpressions? Just remove the spaces if you don't need them. More info about whitespace and quoting in generator expressions can be found at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#whitespace-and-quoting.
